# Css Grid Wrap columns keep row height

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm not sure if this is solvable by css grid and/or css flexbox at all, but I thought I'd give it a try and ask here.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMOWwr

In the codepen you see a css grid with multiple columns, which wrap when the viewport is too small. This is what it should do and it's really nice how easy this is with css grid.

But, to what I'd like to have additionally is that the row heights are equal based on the cell with the most height in that row.

To illustrate this I added more text in one cell in each column and a `<hr>` elements to simulate borders - so, speaking this, I'd like to have the `<hr>` tags to be on the same height in every column, for arbitrary content within a cell.

Thx for any hints,
Marius

Comment: This looks exactly like the 2nd use case for the `subgrid` feature from [this article](https://blogs.igalia.com/mrego/2016/02/12/subgrids-thinking-out-loud/). Unfortunately, this feature has been postponed to the next level of the spec, CSS Grid Level 2.

Comment: Indeed looks exactly like it. Nice, thx for sharing.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Answers should provide code _here_.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use JavaScript to check the maximum height of each cell in each row, and then resize all other cells accordingly.

Something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzYaEY

However perhaps a more idiomatic solution would just be to use a `<table>` element and style it accordingly.

Comment: yeah ok, table element would work, except that a table doesn't wrap, or am I wrong?
And if I think of nested table f.e. it's the same situation as here with css-grid ...

Comment: so yeah, I guess I'll need some JS here, thx for the example, but I prefer to solve it with Dart :P